# How to use Prolog to print a PDF file

Tags: pdf, prolog, postscript, eps

I am a newbie to Prolog and was just wondering if there is a way to print something to a pdf file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you create a PostScript file first and only then convert that file into a PDF file. If you worry about incompatibilities, PDF and PostScript are both from Adobe. PostScript was there first for a decade. PDF is essentially an unreadable form of PostScript.  However, you can edit PostScript files as regular text files. And, even better, PostScript is a full programming language! It is a bit unconventional, and similar to but cleaner than Forth.

I recommend as introductory text [A first guide to PostScript](http://www.tailrecursive.org/postscript/postscript) by 
Peter Weingartner. Don't shy away reading it, it is definitely less effort than reading the documentations of libraries in other programming languages. And, in the end you have a truly device independent way to represent your graphics! Even more, you will be able to talk to a printer directly!

To give you a head start, [here is a tiny quiz](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/romannumerals.eps) about roman numerals as an eps-file. Thus an encapsulated postscript file.

Comment: Nit: while based on earlier work from the 70s, Postscript came out in 83 or 84.

Comment: From the preface of the 1985 reference manual: "The language had its beginnings in 1976 ...". 1978: JaM. 1982: PostScript.

Comment: Thanks. Did you have a look at the quiz above?

Comment: wow. an excellent example: DSC, distinct procset/script, In-Line SpecialFX! I could almost understand the whole thing before previewing. Is that the "real" roman style, with backwards letters? (I lent my paleography books to my mom.)

Comment: You find that kind of roman numbers when glyphs are real types, cast in brass, gilded, thus not engraved, in particular in the 17th and 18th century, like [on the inscription below the quadriga](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Image:Wien_Josefsplatz.jpg). So the mold from the C was reused.  BTW, it never looks good in Unicode: ⅭⅠↃ

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but I think you'd have better chance by calling prolog from a c/c++/java program and export from there.